# (PDE) Parabolic Equation and their BCs and ICs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde, parabolic-pde

I have this PDE with the BCs and ICs

$ u_t=4u_{xx} \\ u(0,t)=u(2,t)=0\quad \text{For All}\quad t>0 \\u(x,0)=f(x) \\  f(x)=10x,\quad x<0,5 \\ f(x)=8,5-7x,\quad 0,5\le x<1,5 \\ f(x)=-8+4x,\quad 1,5\le x< 2$

Please give me some hint for solving this PDE. I know that the BCs is homogeneous, so i can use the separation variable plus fourier series solution. But i'm confused with the ICs.
When i can use them all?
Please guide me to understand all of this.
Thanks and sorry if i have some mistakes.

Comment: You'll need to decompose the initial function $f(x)$ into a Fourier series over $(0,2)$

Comment: What if i do the fourier series one by one? Is it allowed? I mean from 0 to 0,5 i use the fourier series. Then for the second, 0,5 to 1,5 i use the fourier series. So i have 3 solution for each functions. Is it allowed to do like this? Thanks

Comment: That is in fact how you would do it. As long as the terms have the same frequencies.

Comment: One last question please. So if i decompose the initial function. Is it mean i must to sum up the three functions? Like $10x+(8,5-7x)+(-8+4x)$ ?

Comment: Nope. You'll have to do 3 different integrals and add them together to form the Fourier coefficients. Like $$ \int_0^{0.5} 10x \sin\left(\frac{n\pi}{2}x\right)\ dx $$ and so on.